# Whether Time can be reduced for Login?

Tags: javascript, php, html, node.js, ajax

I am thinking of reducing the time of login in web-domain.
My plan goes like this:

- While entering the username, the **onkeyup** event will be generated and will check the database for that username using ***AJAX***.
- It will **yield** that username is found and if the correct password is entered, it will check only for the password taken in the variable.
- So, will the login time be reduced?

Comment: I think time will not reduce because you are making two-time database call   (one time for username and one time for password)that can be done in single call

Comment: No your application will become open. Assume i enter user name admin it checks found Ok .. I enter password admin which is not the password of admin but of some another user and as you will only check password which will be true ..

Comment: Login is a very simple db call and you shouldn't be concerned with this. Anyway, to achieve this, you'll need to store your retrieved username and password in a session so that you can check against your password and not having to call db for a second time. So many potential problems... what if the user submits the login form before you finish the db call (unlikely but still). Think of more issues yourself when you have more experience.